# "Recent Files" entries via command line apps?

Tags: unity, command-line, zeitgeist

I process lots of files via the command line, e.g. using my own shell or python scripts.  Is there an easy way to add the files that I manipulate to the Unity "recent files" list so I can then easily access them via the Unity dash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity uses a system called [Zeitgeist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeitgeist_%28framework%29) for managing that kind of data. There are two proper ways to add things:

- Your Python scripts can add Zeitgeist entries using the higher-level [Python API](http://zeitgeist-project.com/docs/0.8.2/client.html#zeitgeist.client.ZeitgeistClient.insert_event).
- Your shell scripts can use `dbus-send` to work with the lower-level [D-Bus API](http://zeitgeist-project.com/docs/0.8.2/dbus_api.html).

However, I can't give an example because I haven't yet used either. (I use Lubuntu normally and I only know about Zeitgeist because my brother asked me to figure out how to clear out the Recent list in the Unity Dock)